# Is there a way to upgrade a node via MaaS or Juju?

Tags: maas

Is there a way to make the security upgrade on all nodes added to MaaS?
because to make that VM by VM it takes too long time.

Comment: Can you add some detail to your question? Do you mean upgrading the charm on the node or installing security updates on the nodes or doing major distro upgrades on the node? etc.

Comment: installing security updates on the nodes, without make that one bye one.

Comment: it could be an new implementation to insert in MaaS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this kind of management is within MAAS's scope. That sounds like a job for other tools, the ones that come to mind are Landscape (https://landscape.canonical.com/), puppet and chef.

That said, if all your nodes are deployed with MAAS, they will be quite homogeneous, so you can use tools like dsh to execute the same command on multiple nodes, this would save you from having to do it manually node-by-node.

Comment: It maybe a resource the developers could add to MaaS. In effect, in our case all our 500 Virtual Svr are Ubuntu 14.04Lts and they need to receive security upgrade. To make that one by one it takes too much time. As you suggested me I'll try to use dsh,(http://www.unixlore.net/articles/running-remote-commands-multiple-servers-ssh-dsh.html). Landscape costs too much.